# PySpark Dataframe Pushdown

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the following table in SQLServer

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id smallint,
  val, varchar(200)
);
```

I'm trying to query it using SparkSQL's DataFrame API in Python like this:

```
df = sql.read.format("jdbc")
             .option("url", url)
             .option("query", "SELECT * FROM test")
             .option("driver", driver)
             .load()
```

I would like to be able to push down filters to the `id` column in the database using `isin()`, like this:

```
df = df.filter(df['id'].isin([1,2,3]))
```

However, since the id column is a `smallint` in the database, the predicate isn't getting pushed down. If I try to use the same syntax to filter the `val` column, the predicate is successfully pushed down.

Does anyone know if it is possible to pushdown a predicate from Python to the database for a `smallint` column?